# Swift 4 Cannot remove popupViewController from view

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a popupViewController with a UIView as below. The UIView view changes by pressing a button below the UIView. The UIView then changes to one of the coloured view on the right side of diagram. I have a button on each view that I would like to dismiss/ close the popupView to return back to the main ViewController view (ARSCNView), but I can't seem to get it to work? I can actually close the popUpView via the 'close' button which is on the PopUpViewController.

[image]

I have tried to call the function that closes the popupview from within one of the views to the right but it does nothing. Any help would be great.

The popupView is presented as below, from the Main ViewController:

```
 let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:    nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sbPopUpID") as!  popupViewController
    self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
    popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
    
    popOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Do I have to dismiss for example:
1.FirstViewController (Blue)
2.MasterViewController (white)
3.PopUpViewController

to get to the ARSCNView?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: it's a lot of view and code to understand, could you put it in a git?

Comment: Hello, @ClaudioCastro the PopupView with menu is actually this project: ( https://github.com/ramprasadios/HorizontalScreenTransitions) thank you

Comment: I just downloaded your code at night, 10h after my first comment, and from what I've seen it's a little different from the one presented in the question. Did you solve it? If I understand your problem correctly, there are some ways you can solve it. One is with delegate, causing the popview to pop the child and itself. The other is to pop the two views directly onto the view stack. There is still a third. I no longer saw the close button or the parent view where you wanted to go. That's why I didn't go into the problem anymore. Let me know if you solved it or not

Comment: See if this is what you want. I put the button only on the first one, just to exemplify.  https://github.com/ccastroelo/HorizontalScreenTransitions

Comment: Hello @ClaudioCastro I have just cloned your version and tested it and it looks exactly what I meant. That's amazing, thank you for your answer.

Comment: I'm glad you got it resolved. I will put the answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use delegate as follows below:

In your childrens view. (example)

```
protocol ChildrenViewControllerDelegate {
    func closeAll()
}

class ChildrenViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate : ChildrenViewControllerDelegate?
    
    @IBAction func close(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.closeAll()
    }
...
```

and in your parent view, set the ChildrenViewControllerDelegate and:

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController, ChildrenViewControllerDelegate    

    func closeAll() {
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated:true)
    }

// Set/pass the delegate on children:

   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            self.chindrenVc = segue.destination as? ChildrenViewController
            self.childrenVc?.delegate = self
   }
```